# Unique events 0, but total events > 0

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track mail openings. I've got cases such like this, where I have a bunch of Total Events but no unique events (second row). What does this mean?

Also, why the unique events is zero when the fact is I opened the email? So confusing.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing a session hit scope metric with a page hit scope dimension.
See a similar answer here: [How can I have more than zero Events, but zero Unique Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761948/how-can-i-have-more-than-zero-events-but-zero-unique-events/49785725?r=SearchResults#49785725)